# RAID 0 using AMD onboard controller and Samsung 850 EVOs

Tags: windows-7, raid-0

I am having the same issue. I am using Win7pro 64bit, the onboard RAID controller from an ASUS sabertooth 990FX R2.0, 2x250GB Samsung 850 EVO SSDs, and a 2TB Seagate Barracuda HDD.
I have the latest drivers and the UEFI is updated to the latest firmware. I have done plenty of online research and even called ASUS customer support so many times that the tier 2 team will not talk to me anymore. I have done everything I can think of and everything ASUS has asked me to do and NOTHING WORKS.

Here is what I have done. The UEFI recognizes the 2 SSDs just fine. Windows recognizes the individual SSDs just fine. When I enter the RAID controller, it recognizes the SSDs and proceeds to configure the RAID 0 as normal. As soon as I turn on the RAID controller in the UEFI, the Windows install that is on my HDD BSODs and resets in the middle of loading until I turn the RAID controller off. If I try to do a fresh install on the RAID disk with the HDD still attached, Windows does not recognize either the HDD or the RAID disk until I use the ASUS motherboard drivers for RAID and then it will only recognize the HDD. I can't load the drivers into my HDD install with the RAID controller on and if I turn it off and install them, Windows accepts them but still BSODs upon load up and a fresh install will still not recognize the RAID disk(or the HDD until I load drivers.) Windows repair scans indicate no other problem other than new hardware when the RAID is on. If I remove the HDD from the equation to do a fresh install, the RAID drive is not recognized by Windows no matter if I use the ASUS drivers or not. An interesting side note, I switched the UEFI from AHCI mode to IDE mode and it acts like I turned on the RAID controller and Windows will BSOD just like it did when in RAID mode. I don't know if that is related or not, but it sure seems to be.

I bought all these parts and built this computer myself. I specifically bought the SSDs and motherboard so that I could do a RAID 0 and get those 1 GB/sec read speeds I have wanted ever since I knew they were possible, not to mention being able to use a half terabyte RAID instead of 2 individual quarter terabyte SSDs. I am not interested in doing a RAID 1. I don't care if the RAID 0 will make much real world difference or not. This is not the point. I don't need advice on what people think I SHOULD want. I know what I want and what I want is not working... I am about ready to give up on ASUS and just buy a RAID controller card. I honestly think ASUS needs to reprogram the drivers and maybe even reprogram a firmware update for the UEFI. If anyone can help me solve this issue it would be most appreciated.

Comment: For the BSoD after installing RAID drivers for the existing HDD installation - could you share the error code? Is it the same as the other BSoDs? For the fresh install - when you mention loading the RAID drivers do you mean doing so at install-time, or post-installation? (If the fresh install did not fail, I would've suspected that enabling RAID messed up device IDs that a boot repair could've fixed. But something else is wrong here.)

Comment: Is the HDD on the same controller as the SSD? If it is then changing the controller mode from regular AHCI to RAID will not just switch RAID on for the SSDs but also for the HDD. (Even if the HDD is not part of an array). The last requires different drivers (usually done with a fresh install of windows and drivers loaded via F6),

Comment: The BSOD error code flashes by so fast that I can't write it down. I would just rather do a fresh install on the newly created RAID 0 drive... If only windows would recognize it. I load the drivers pre-install and windows fails to recognize the RAID drive. I can deal with doing a fresh install, but the important thing is for Windows to recognize the RAID disk in the first place. This has been my problem all along.

Answer (score 1):

It is fully possible to get where your trying to go. but i can only cover some of what MAY be the problems you can have.

Switching from compability (IDE) mode to ACHI to RAID , the drivers in the windows system must be setup or the system will flat out crash. ACHI is supported by the RAID mode, but it even can crash when switching from ACHI to RAID.  The windows 7 system has no design to Fix this automatically. The user has to find out how to change the drivers to match.
This information is all over the web, it is not just pushing one button, but many many people have sucessfully done it, the pain in the butt that it is.

Because of that, a person can go nuts when they go to rearrange things and switch things back and forth. A builder then prefers to have thier layout figured before putting in the drives even, and to never be switching that stuff ever again.   It is fully understandable that when something goes wrong, we try things , that is how we normally fix things , but once you understand how this can go badly trying ends even if that means you have to start from scratch.

Another thing that is so minimally discussed, I do not even know the facts of it. When you INIT a drive on the RAID system (has been true for intel promice adapatec)  It stores specific data on the drive itself , on some first blocks. I am sure it was not intended, but it happens, that if you remove that drive from the RAID , it can completly FAIL to work on a regular SATA IDE mode port.  All you have to do is remove that INIT by fully and properly removing it at the RAID bios.  This could be the other thing that goes badly for you.

Take the 2 together, be they fully accurate statements or not, every move you make is collapsing it, when my theme here is Create a specific setup, Lock it down, do not change and try things.  The data should be all backed up, and a bild with raid and all (doesnt have to) but is far easier to start with the disks all clean and not initied on a raid, and in ONE mode RAID that you will use from now on to eternity.

Also not to forget Flashing the BIOS/UEFI Defaulting the BIOS/UEFI Or loosing the settings, or bringing in a save profile, or not having a CMOS battery working, or anything that would reset the settings in the bios. The first thing you check when running a RAID setup via the motherboard is that (again) you set it back to the RAID setting.

Setup your disk and RAID then only in the RAID BIOS both arrays and "other"drives (not to be confused with spare), no where else, no other software. Do not combine windows raid or dynamic  with a hardware created raid. Un-Setup your disks in the raid bios , nowhere else. The second reason for this, is the drives will be assembled when you are not running these OSes and software, making it stay the same again. *

So that is the tips that may assist you in solving your own problem.

Other conciderations for the OSes themselves not the hardware:
Where the EFI partition is, the method of boot UEFI or Compatability MBR Where the BCD Bootloader or GRUB or whatever, so the pointers to the working OS are correct.
Installing windows 7 IN RAID mode requiring drivers from a flash disk or something, otherwise it is installed in compatability IDE mode and , then the user goes through the process of switching that manually in a safe mode.
All the newer windows sytems identify a disk based on the ID of the disk GUID, any arrays formed may not have the same ID the operating system is pointed to boot to, Editing the BCD to repoint the OS may be required.

*Note: There are pros and cons for a more hardware raid , and pros and cons for a software only raid. It just is not covered here.

Comment: I don't mind doing a fresh install of windows... If only Windows would recognize the RAID disk in the first place, Drivers or not.

Comment: Yea you have to do the F6 install SCSI drivers thing and have that intel install driver available to point to, and have the driver installed at install.. That is the method many people will use.  It is not just any driver either, it is a specific intel minimal driver used to install the OS.  I instead use a complex method of installing on a non-raid creating an image backup, switching the drivers, shifting the clone image backup to the raid, I could not even write all the steps that is, because it was long ago and because of backups I only do it one time. stumbling about  safe mode booting.